# RxSwift, adding a CocoaAction to a button will have a side effect when other observables bind to it

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I add a CocoaAction to a button, like

```
var speakBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Speak", style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
speakBtn.rx.action = viewModel.speakAction
```

After that, there is a textView's text to bind to it, like

```
if let speakBtn = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.first {
    textValid.bindTo(speakBtn.rx.isEnabled)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Then, the result is wrong. If I comment the code which adds the cocoaAction to the button, when the app run, the textView's text is nil, so the speakBtn will be unable to click.

But now, the speakBtn is enable to click.

Anyone can give me a explain? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.

I should not use the method to init speakAction:

```
action: Action<String, Bool> = Action(workFactory: { input in
  return networkLibrary.checkEmailExists(input)
})
```

I should use the method to init speakAction:

```
action: Action<String, Bool> = Action(enabledIf: validEmailAddress, workFactory: { input in
  return networkLibrary.checkEmailExists(input)
})
```

So, the right code should be like:

```
let textValid = textView.rx.text.orEmpty
    .map{ $0.characters.count > 0 }
    .shareReplay(1)
viewModel.speakAction = CocoaAction(enabledIf: textValid, workFactory: { Void -> Observable<Void> in
    return Observable.create { observer in
        observer.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create()
    }
})
textValid.bindTo(hintLabel.rx.isHidden)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
textValid.bindTo(speakBtn.rx.isEnabled)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
speakBtn.rx.action = viewModel.speakAction
```